# Interpretation of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(i\,k\,x)\,\mathrm{dx}$

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

According to another solution here the solution should sound like $2\,\pi\,\delta(k)$

I ask myself: what's the matter of including that factor $2\pi$ ? The reason being $\delta(k)$ is infinite for $0$ and $0$ else, that $2\,\pi$ actually has no effect at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think of the local value at a point. Here we are dealing with [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)).

The Dirac delta distribution $\delta$ satisfies
$\int \delta(k) \, f(k) \, dk = f(0)$
and so, multiplication by $2\pi$ gives another value:
$$\int 2 \pi\delta(k) \, f(k) \, dk = 2\pi f(0).$$